# Referencing equations in LibreOffice/OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, equations, numbering

Equations in LibreOffice (OpenOffice) can be autonumbered. How can I reference equations in text by that numbers so when equation numbers then references in document updated automaticaly.

**For example** in initial document were two equations:

[image: equation before]

New equation was inserted:

[image: equation after]

How to avoid this. What is the "special way" to reference equation in document text so it will be updated automatically when equation number change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Uhm, you are referencing equation 1, so it's still 1 afterwards. Try referencing equation 2...</sub>

Look for functionality to update the references if the above is by accident and the problem persists.

You can [number equations in OpenOffice](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Numbering_equations):

1. Choose Insert > Cross-reference from the menu bar.
2. On the Cross-references tab, under Type, select Text.
3. Under Selection, select the equation number.
4. Under Format, select Reference.
5. Click Insert.

Answer (score 4):

You could also make numbered equations in a special way though. For this You should type right in Your document `fn` and then press F3. A template for a numbered equation should appear.

What F3 calls is the autotext expansion. Here You call autotext which has a shortcut `fn` - it stands for "Formula Numbering".

Comment: This solution is just great as it produces exactly what I want without the need to manually define cross references!